# Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery got XA exception

Tags: java, jboss, jms, jboss7.x, hornetq

Any thoughts on what could be causing this exception:

```
03:54:34,497 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA016027: Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery got XA exception XAException.XAER_RMERR: javax.transaction.xa.XAException: Error trying to connect to any providers for xa recovery
    at org.hornetq.jms.server.recovery.HornetQXAResourceWrapper.getDelegate(HornetQXAResourceWrapper.java:275) [hornetq-jms-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.jms.server.recovery.HornetQXAResourceWrapper.recover(HornetQXAResourceWrapper.java:77) [hornetq-jms-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:503) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.resourceInitiatedRecoveryForRecoveryHelpers(XARecoveryModule.java:471) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.bottomUpRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:385) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.periodicWorkSecondPass(XARecoveryModule.java:166) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.doWorkInternal(PeriodicRecovery.java:789) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.run(PeriodicRecovery.java:371) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create session factory, server locator is closed (maybe it has been garbage collected)
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.assertOpen(ServerLocatorImpl.java:1823) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:699) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.jms.server.recovery.HornetQXAResourceWrapper.connect(HornetQXAResourceWrapper.java:321) [hornetq-jms-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.jms.server.recovery.HornetQXAResourceWrapper.getDelegate(HornetQXAResourceWrapper.java:251) [hornetq-jms-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 8):

Do these commands in your SQL console with SYS user, it's work perfecly for me :

```
  GRANT SELECT ON sys.dba_pending_transactions TO <user>;
  GRANT SELECT ON sys.pending_trans$ TO <user>;
  GRANT SELECT ON sys.dba_2pc_pending TO <user>;
  GRANT EXECUTE ON sys.dbms_xa TO <user>;
  GRANT FORCE ANY TRANSACTION TO <user>;
```

change `<user>` with the user jboss use to connect to DB

Comment: GRANT EXECUTE ON sys.dbms_system TO user;

Comment: According to JBoss this is the correct answer. Ref: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ARJUNA016027LocalXARecoveryModulexaRecoveryGotXAExceptionXAExceptionXAERRMERR

Comment: A complete explaination of the problem in the Red Hat website : https://access.redhat.com/solutions/22274

Answer (score 7):

I also faced the same problem. Apart from the link posted by Claudiu, [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=914860) link is also helpful.

As per one of the user's suggestion, stopping AS7, clearing out the `jbossas-7/jbossas-7/standalone`'s **data** and **tmp** directories, and restarting AS7 solved my problem.

Posting it here might help someone.

Comment: The cleaning up did not help.